# Autowire class which extends non-container class

Tags: spring, components, autowired

I have next structure:

```
@Component public abstract class
HuginJob extends QuartzJobBean {...}


@Component("CisxJob") public class
CisxJob extends HuginJob {...}
```

Now I want to test CisxJob:

```
 @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)

 @ContextConfiguration({"/applicationContext-test.xml" })

public class CisxJobTest {

     @Autowired
     @Qualifier("CisxJob")
     private CisxJob          cisxJob;
..... }
```

Here is part of `applicationContext-test.xml`

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="no.hugin.jobscheduler" />
```

Error is

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
>   Error creating bean with name 'no.hugin.jobscheduler.job.cisx.CisxJobTest': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;
>   nested exception is rg.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Could not autowire field: private no.hugin.jobscheduler.job.cisx.CisxJob
>   no.hugin.jobscheduler.job.cisx.CisxJobTest.cisxJob; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: 
>   No matching bean of type [no.hugin.jobscheduler.job.cisx.CisxJob] found for dependency:
>   expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. 
>   Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier(value=CisxJob)}
>       at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:286)
>   .............

The problem is in extending of QuartzJobBean - but I need it.

Thank you

Comment: Do you have any aspects applied to your beans (transactional, etc)?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry - I fixed post.

Comment: Yes. 

`<context:annotation-config />`
`<context:component-scan base-package="no.hugin.jobscheduler" />`
`<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`
`<bean id="simpleProfiler"
class="no.hugin.jobscheduler.aop.BasicProfiler" />`

Karramba!! I've removed it and it started working!!!!!!

But what is the problem?
Why I can't use aspect?

BasicProfiler - is just logs time of executions

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is in a way Spring generates AOP proxies. When class being proxied implements any interfaces, Spring by default creates a JDK proxy that implement these interfaces.

Since `QuartzJobBean` implements an interface `Job`, `CisxJob` is proxied as `Job`, and that proxy can't be autowired to the field of type `CisxJob`.

There are two solutions:

- If your bean implement any interfaces, create an interface for its business methods as well, and use it as a field type:

  ```
   public interface CisxJob { ... }

   @Component("CisxJob")
   public class CisxJobImpl extends HuginJob implements CisxJob {...}
  ```
- Use proxy-target-class mode:

  ```
   <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class = "true" />
  ```

**See also:**

- [7.6 Proxying mechanisms](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-proxying)